# Один обработчик события Click для некоторых кнопок

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Есть большое количество кнопок на форме, для них всех я создал обработчик событий:

```
foreach (UIElement c in LayoutRoot.Children)
{
    if (c is Button)
    {

        ((Button)c).Click += Button_Click;
    }
}
```

Как мне сделать так чтобы этот обработчик событий создавался только для некоторых кнопок,а другие кнопки получали свой отдельный обработчик событий?

Comment: А зачем так мудрить. Создайте обработчик и пропишите руками в XAML для каждой нужной кнопки  этот общий один обработчик.

Comment: А по какому критерию вы хотите навешивать обработчик? Как ваш код будет определять, нужно навешивать его или нет?

Comment: у меня есть одна кнопка для которой мне нужен отдельный обработчик,можно определять по имени

Comment: Ну так напишите `if (c.Name == "...")`, где проблема?

Comment: Name подчеркивает красным

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
Button b = c as Button;
if (b != null && b.Name != "...")
    b.Click += Button_Click;
```

Comment: Спасибо,не подскажешь, как в самом обработчике узнать какая кнопка была нажата(допустим определялось ее имя)?

Comment: @РустемВалеев: Очень просто, кнопка приходит в качестве `sender`'а.